# Get value of php file from the server using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I made a php page that gets all the files(file names) from a particular directory. I want to use ajax to get the value from the php file. I have never used ajax. Can anyone suggest me a way to achieve this?

My php code is pretty simple i guess. It will be used in a dropdown, thats why there is "option".

```
    <?php

foreach(glob('../files/videos/*.*') as $filename){
     $name1 = str_replace('../files/videos/', '', $filename);
     $ext = pathinfo($name1, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
     $notneeded=".".$ext;
     $name = str_replace($notneeded, '', $name1);

     echo "<option  value='".$name1."'>".$name."</option>"."<br/>";


 }

 ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: jquery's load is a simple way to do this: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thank you so much, jquery did the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      <div style="float:left;" id="success"></div>
<div id="error"></div>
<script>
$("#success").load("yourfile.php", function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "error") {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use echo, but a more useful way would be to encode the results in a JSON string. However you can do what you want like so.

```
$.get('url/to/php/file.php',function(data){
    $('select').html(data);
});
```

This is a jQuery solution of course just to demonstrate the simplicity of what you are trying to achieve. You can write all of this in vanilla javascript. Basically a XHR request, and then inject the returned `data` into the select element in your page.

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't use your code but it was still jquery. Here is what @Dagon recommended 

<script>
$("#success").load("filenames.php", function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "error") {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
  </script>

Comment: Yeah there are several way to skin an AJAX cat, but either way. I'm not always up to date on which way is the "correct" jquery method. Their best practices seems to be different every few months.